# WPF: Detect Ctrl+MWheelUp/Down

Tags: wpf

I can bind to <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+LeftClick</kbd>, but how can I bind to mouse/scroll wheel actions?

I am trying to do something like increase/decrease font size, like in a browser.

I want to set <kbd>Ctrl+MWheelUp</kbd> to the increase font size

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In constructor add event to PreviewMouseWheel

```
PreviewMouseWheel += Window_PreviewMouseWheel;
```

And then in the handler detect the key

```
private void Window_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers != ModifierKeys.Control)
        return;

    if (e.Delta > 0)
        ZoomIn();

    else if (e.Delta < 0)
        ZoomOut();
}
```

Comment: For further reference: @LukaszMadon - the code you proposed will check if AT LEAST Ctrl is pressed (it may also be Ctrl+Shif, Ctrl+Alt, etc.) and then will trigger. If you want to check whether ONLY Ctrl was pressed, use (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control).